# Overwrite community model method issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, overrides, model

This is my config xml from my custom module:

```
<models>
    <emailtester>
         <rewrite>
             <variable>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mailer_Variable</variable>
         </rewrite>
    </emailTester>
</models>
```

This is my model:

```
class Mynamespace_MyModule_Model_Mailer_Variable extends Yireo_EmailTester_Model_Mailer_Variable
{
    public function getVariables()
    { 
         echo 1; exit();
    }

}
```

I would like to overwrite the method: `Yireo_EmailTester_Model_Mailer_Variable::getVariables`

This is the Yireo_EmailTester class:

```
class Yireo_EmailTester_Model_Mailer_Variable extends Varien_Object
{
    .....
    public function getVariables()
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I followed this [Overwrite community Model file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71778/overwrite-community-model-file) , but still I cannot get the `echo 1; exit();` Any idea why ?

Thank you!

Comment: try changing `<variable>` to `<mailer_variable>` in config.xml under `<rewrite>` tag

Comment: @Piyush  that was it . Thnx. you can post it as an answer, I will accept it :) with some explication why use `mailer_variable` instead of `variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong code in your `config.xml`, you should have below code

```
<models>
    <emailtester>
         <rewrite>
             <mailer_variable>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mailer_Variable</mailer_variable>
         </rewrite>
    </emailTester>
</models>
```

node after the `<rewrite>` is the path of you model file after `Model` directory. In your case you are rewriting `Yireo_EmailTester_Model_Mailer_Variable` file so it  will be `mailer_variable`

Comment: Typo there, variable_mailer should be mailer_variable ;)